# Sending an answer to the Low Quality review queue

Tags: discussion, answers, quality, review-queue

**What is the right way to mark that an answer should be sent to the Low Quality review queue?**

I ask this because twice recently I have flagged an answer as Low Quality or Not an Answer and had the flag declined because "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". My intent in flagging was never to ask a moderator to take decisive action. I only wanted it sent to the queue so I could get other users' opinions on whether the answer is worth keeping or not.

As I write this I am now wondering, is the flag decline actually from a moderator, or is that the response I get when it has been sent to review and the other users don't think that it should be removed?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. I do know that after a given time period, those flags _do_ show up in the moderator queue - how long that is I'm not sure. The idea is that the review queue should handle it first and _then_ it shows up for moderators, if it's not, but I'm unsure what happened here. I don't see any reviews for your recent flags... maybe it just didn't get looked at in the review queue?

Comment: @ElysianFields My most recent flag was declined in under 24 hours. If it was supposed to hit the review before going to the moderators, that seems like a potential bug? Either that or a very short delay time.

Comment: An obvious example of this problem is link only answers. If they get on the LQQ then there is an obvious option to choose but it has to get on the queue first and some users trhink that they way to deal with link only is not sufficient for NAA.

Comment: @ElysianFields [15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for finding that. And wow, that is an *incredibly* small amount of time. No wonder it doesn't get a chance to go through the review queue!